# Initialize logger inside dll

Tags: c++, dll, g2log

I'm trying to use the g2log logging library inside my DLL project using VS2012.

The problem is that looking at the documentation [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288827/g2log-An-efficient-asynchronous-logger-using-Cplus#TOC_initialization)」 it needs to be initialized at the beginning and stay alive for the lifespan of the program.
Since I don't have a main, and using DllMain doesn't help, where could I do the initialization?
(I started this project recently so I also accept suggestions about other options for a logging library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using VS2012 you can use C++11 which means you can have thread-safe statics so you can add a global function:

```
Logger& get_logger ()
{
   static Logger logger;
   return logger;
}
```

And then use that get_logg() to get hold of the object (if you need more elaborate construction/initialization you can also do that inside this function using std::atomic<> from C++11). Here is a version using std::atomic_flag:

```
Logger& get_logger ()
{
   static std::atomic_flag is_initialized;
   if (! is_initialized.test_and_set()) {
     /* do lots of initialization */
   }

   return some_object;
}
```

I do not use or know the g2log library so I cannot give more explicit examples.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that but, a good start. I'll work my way out using your suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning on doing something [similar](https://github.com/d-led/g2log-dll). Somewhere, you are using that dll. In your user code you might call the initialization procedure, where you could also configure g2log.

Comment: Yes, I only hoped to find a way so that it would be transparent for the projects the library. In the dll I basically export only static factories, maybe I can use that.

Comment: if you separate g2log into a dll, then maybe you could do that there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I see, putting the logger in a separate library also could be useful for using it throughout the solution with different projects, I didn't think of that!